# access old files in /opt folder after making a different partition to mount on /opt mount point

Tags: linux, filesystems

I am using openSuse 13.2. Due to low disk space on root partition I created a separate partition and mounted it at `/opt`. Before this I backed-up all the data in the old `opt` directory. After mounting the new partition on '/opt' successfully the remaining storage space of root partition is still the same.

If I have lost the handle/access to files on the old `opt` directory on the root partition then how can I delete those files to free up the space on root partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unmount the new /opt and you will see the old /opt on the root partition again. Then you can clear it / delete it's contents and mount the new /opt again.

To make stuff safer, unmount the /opt, move the old /opt to /oldopt, create a new /opt with the same ownership and permissions and then mount /opt again. Then you can compare /opt and /oldopt and delete /oldopt after you made sure everything is fine.